# Javascript name generator

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make JS output a full name based on input from both radio buttons and text. I'm having an issue as I want it to output the person's choice, yet whenever I click male or female, it's always displaying as Male (plus the text). The code I've got at the moment for the output is:

```
window.onload = initAll;

function initAll() {
document.getElementById("sillySubmit").onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById("msgField").innerHTML = getSillyName();
    return false;
}
}

function getSillyName() {

var x = $('input[id]').click(function() {
        ($('input[id]:checked').val()); 
});

var lastName1 = ["lots of names"]; 

var lastName2 = ["lots more names" ]; 

var lastNm = document.getElementById("lName").value.toUpperCase();
var validName = true;

if (lastNm == "") {
    validName = false;
}
else {
    var lastNum1 = lastNm.charCodeAt(0) - 65;
    var lastNum2 = lastNm.charCodeAt((lastNm.length-1)) - 65;

    if (lastNum1 < 0 || lastNum1 > 25 || lastNum2 < 0 || lastNum2 > 25) {
        validName = false;
    }
}     

if (!validName) {
    document.getElementById("lName").focus();
    document.getElementById("lName").select();
    return "I say. Something gone a bit squiffy here. Try again...";
}
return "Your name is " + x + ' ' + lastName1[lastNum1] + ' '
+ lastName2[lastNum2]; //add in comparisons later on
```

}

where 'x' is representing male and 'y' is female. What can I add/change so that it displays the correct preference?

Comment: Please share the entire function snippet so that we get a better idea.

Comment: What do you expect the `||` to do? It doesn't work.

Comment: Whole function added..

Comment: At first change line 5 of your code from   `document.getElementById("msgField").innerHTML = x;`to `document.getElementById("msgField").innerHTML = y;`

Comment: All changed.. it now seems to possible to select both male and female radio buttons though?

Comment: Set the male and female  radio button into a common `radio button group`. Then you can select only one, they will toggle.

Comment: Thanks - it's now selecting the radio buttons properly, however nothing is showing on pressing submit now. (Original Updated)

Comment: What do you expect your var x to be ?

Comment: The value of either male/female

Comment: Okay, I don't want to cause trouble here. In ca. 1 hour I will try an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see your html, so I have to guess a lot. I assume you have a lot of input elements, all with an id-attribute, and your female/male buttons are two of them. Those buttons have a value being either 'on' or 'off', and in some browsers its always 'on'. So don't look for value. Further radio buttons have a property `checked` being either **true** or **false**.
You don't need to attach a click-handler to get the state.

So the first lines of your getSillyName() could look like:

```
function getSillyName() {
    var x;
    if (document.getElementById(/* female id here */).checked) {
        x = 'Mrs.' // change string to whatever you want to see
    } else if (document.getElementById(/* male id here */).checked) {
        x = 'Mr.' // as above
    } else x = 'cat'; // possibly both are unchecked
    /* the very important next line in your code should be: */
    console.log(x);
    /* this important line move step by step further down your code */
    console.log(/* and put in here what you want to check */);

    /* rest of code here */
}
```

After that your element **#msgField** should show something.

Answer (score 0):

> What can I add/change so that it displays the correct preference?

If I understood correctly, the answer will be: parentheses.

The code will become:

```
"Your name is " + (x || y) + ' ' + lastName1[lastNum1] + ' ' + lastName2[lastNum2];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try defining the first name before returning the value.

```
if(gender == 'male')
 firstname = ...
else
 firstName = ...
return 'Your name is ' + firstname + ' ' + lastName1[lastNum1] + '     ' + lastName2[lastNum2];
```

I hope that helps.